# php truncating field issue

Tags: javascript, php

Iam truncating a large field in php. Its all working fine except that iam getting an error on the following line. Iam truncating more than 25 characters with a more hyperlink. When i click the more link, a javascript alert triggers with the actual data.

```
$length_limit = 25; //limit to this number of characters
$actual_length = strlen($value); //count characters in the $value
$original_text = $value;
$truncated_text = substr($value,0,$length_limit); 


if($actual_length <= $length_limit){
$value = $original_text;
} else {
$value = $truncated_text." ... <a onclick='alert(\"'.$original_text.'\")'>more</a>";
```

Iam getting the error from the last line $value=.... May be some quoatation mark problem. Can someone pls help me with the same.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Iam getting an error "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal"

Comment: Use `stripslashes` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
echo $value = $truncated_text." ... <a onclick=\"alert('".$original_text."')\">more</a>";
```

Comment: You are welcome please mark as right if its OK for you

Comment: One more doubt. Is there a way, instead of alert i can use a popup window? I can put as a seperate question. I can accept the answer only after 3 minutes. Will do the same.

Comment: @Anant : Thanks. :)

Comment: @SanjuMenon  yes you can instead of direct alert ,call a function into onclick and pass data to that function and write that function which will open a pop-up window with that data

Comment: @SanjuMenon : It depends on requirement. You can do anything.

Comment: ok sure. i can try. Not well versed with Javascript functions. will try it

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below (anyone of them):-

```
echo $value = $truncated_text.' ... <a onclick=\'alert("'.$original_text.'")\'>more</a>';
```

**Or**

```
 echo $value = $truncated_text." ... <a onclick=\"alert('".$original_text."')\">more</a>";
```

***Pop-Up Window code:-***

```
<style>
#edit_price_background_overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999999;
}
#mainnew_window {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<div id="edit_price_background_overlay">
  <div id="mainnew_window">

  </div>
</div>
<?php
$value = 'dhgffdhgfhfhfhghgfhgfhgfhfghfghgfhgfhgfhgfgfhgfhgfhgfhgfhfgrtdyretrertertretgfdvfgvdfgdfbdfgdfbgfnbgbgfhnhhethfgbgfdnggrehgteggbfdvgfdfgergfdgfdrfgrdfgert4gtrhnfgbfdbvcvcbvcbbvcbhrgdghgyfgbfdbgfvfdbtgf';
$length_limit = 25; //limit to this number of characters
$actual_length = strlen($value); //count characters in the $value
$original_text = $value;
$truncated_text = substr($value,0,$length_limit); 


if($actual_length <= $length_limit){
echo $value = $original_text;
} else {
echo $value = $truncated_text." ... <a onclick=\"showdata('".$original_text."','mainnew_window','edit_price_background_overlay')\">more</a>";
}
?>

<script>
function showdata(mytext,innerdiv,outerdiv){

    var elem = document.getElementById(innerdiv);
    var elem2 = document.getElementById(outerdiv);
    console.log(elem);
    if(typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {
        document.getElementById(innerdiv).innerHTML = mytext;

        document.getElementById(outerdiv).style.display = 'block';  
      }
}

</script>
```

Note:- put this whole code in `php` file as it is and check.

Comment: Thank you Anand. This solution also works for me. :)

Comment: @SanjuMenon  i have added pop-up window code too. check once. Just for your help.:):)

Comment: Thank you so much Anant. Surely i will check it and let you know on this. Once more really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @SanjuMenon  it's a simple pop-up code(not fancy). you need to modify css accordingly to make it more good in looks. Thanks and welcome.

Comment: Thank you so much.